# Filter based on scripted field in an aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation

Here is my source code:

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "datetime": {
              "gte": "2017-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
              "lte": "2018-03-31T23:59:59.999Z"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "all_match": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "all": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "jobs": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "job_num",
            "size": 200000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "latest_job": {
              "top_hits": { 
                "size": 1,
                "sort": [{"rec_date": "desc"}],
                "script_fields": {
                  "reqd_flag":{
                    "script": {
                      "lang": "painless",
                      "inline": "params['_source']['required_flag'] == 'Y' ? 0 : 1"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I need to filter out the records returned in '**latest_job**' aggregation based on the value present in the field '**reqd_flag**'.

**NOTE**: '**all_match**' aggregation was created as a work around to apply bucket_path.

Any input / pointers / suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

[ElasticSearch forum link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/filter-based-on-scripted-field-in-an-aggregation/128976)

[GitHub link](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/29648)